# Emacs js2-mode Syntax Error

Tags: emacs, js2-mode

I am using emacs (js2-mode) for coding javaScript. Here is a simple code snippet where emacs always shows me a syntax error:

```
<script>
    var x = function (a, b)
    {
        return a * b;
    };
</script>
```

The "{" and "return a" are always colored in red, can somebody tell me why? Has anyone worked with js2-mode so far?

Comment: 1. js2-mode version?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem arises from the script tags you have in the code, as there shouldn't be any HTML in a JavaScript file, hence the syntax errors.